# Objective-C struct property pointer cannot be made via self.prop?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, lvalue, nscoder

I've just encountered a little surprise whilst writing NSCoder support into a class. I have a class A which contains an exposed 'color' property of an rgb struct type. I have another class B which extends A.

To encode the color property within class B's encodeWithCoder method I've first wrapped it into an NSValue like so:

```
[NSValue value:&(self.color)]
```

However using this code causes the following compilation error:

```
Lvalue required as unary '&' operand.
```

It's easy enough to get around by simply copying self.color to a method-scope value before wrapping with NSValue, but I'd like to understand the rule for when this will happen, and why it occurs. Will this happen with any @synthesize property due to there being no need for a true class field of that property name to exist, hence no guaranteed object to point to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is simple enough. The compiler turns a property access:

```
self.color
```

into a method call*

```
[self color]
```

which means that `&(self.color)` turns into `&([self color])`. Then the compiler complains, because you can't take the address of a method call.

---

*If you were assigning to the property, the assignment would be transformed into a call to the setter: `self.color = aColor;` -> `[self setColor:aColor];`.

Comment: Concise and just the right amount of detail, thanks Josh! Giving you the points since WTP clearly adjusted his answer to repeat what you said just after you posted.

Comment: It didn't seem to me that WTP was maliciously copying me, but I'm glad you found my answer useful.

Comment: It wasn't malicious in the purest sense, and I'm grateful for his original help, but it annoys me when people on here adjust their answer to mimic content of a better answer that comes along. Your answer is exactly what's needed, that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get the address of something returned by a function (or method). You need to get the address of the `color` ivar directly (i.e. `&color`). In your case though, I recommend using the approach you proposed yourself (`id tempCol = self.color; [NSValue value:&tempCol];`).

---

Note that a method is invoked when using dot notation.

```
self.color
// is equal to
[self color]
```

`&([self color])` is also impossible because `&` is resolved at compile-time, not at runtime. The return value of `[self color]` and `self.color` (which are equal) aren't yet known at compile-time (even when using `@synthesize`, since you can change a method's implementation in Objective-C at runtime (e.g. with method swizzling or using categories)).

---

It seems that you don't fully understand what `@synthesize` does, so I'll explain. :)

Basically what `@synthesize` does is this: the compiler generates methods and their implementations from the given property names.

For example, this property:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSColor *color;
```

Together with this synthesization:

```
@synthesize color;
```

Will insert this code for you in the `@implementation`:

```
- (NSColor *)color {
  return color;
}

- (void)setColor:(NSColor *)newColor {
  if (color == newColor) { return; }
  NSColor *theOldColor = color;
  color = [newColor retain];
  [theOldColor release];
}
```

---

When you like to use your own setter or getter, you simply define these in the `@implementation` by using the same method names. You could, for example, return a default color if none is set yet:

```
- (NSColor *)color {
  if (color) { return color; }
  return [NSColor whiteColor];
}
```

Now the compiler will generate the setter, but not the getter: it will use the getter you provided, you can still use it with `self.color`.

---

You may want to take a look at [Apple's guide on properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html).

Comment: I suppose it seems unobvious to me because I've not been working in a language with auto-setters/getters of late! Thanks WTP.